# Touchscreen kinda works and doesnt work

Tags: touchscreen, stylus

On my Laptop "HP Pavilion x360 14-cd0200ng" the touchscreen works at first. When im using Xournal++ at some moment its like im puting an invisible finger on the touchscreen, when trying to scroll down i scale the page up and down.

After that only limited things work, like the application button on the bottom left.

I tried to calebrate the touchscreen using xinput-calibrator, well it wont register one point.

In order to get the touchscreen back running i have to restart the laptop or disable and reenable the xinput device.

On xinput list the device is listet as "ELAN 2514:00 04F3:2630".

I think it has something to do with the stylus because while writing this, the touchscreen still works.
Is there some fix to get it running without restarting it every 10-20min?

Every information is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Now i found out the problem wasnt at ubuntu. It only happens in xournal++.
In order to "force" the problem i made the zoom gesture with a finger and the stylus.

In order to fix it, under "edit -> preferences -> touchscreen -> hand recognition" check the box, i put it to 0,5s and now it works like a charm.

The thing i still dont get, is why the touchscreen stopped working outside of xournal++.